# ASP MVC Controller is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

To make it easier for myself to unit test my application, I'm trying to implement the Repository pattern by moving my data-access functionality into a separate repository class.

My data-access class in my repository:

```
public class ErrorRepository : IErrorRepository
{
    public ErrorModel Errors { get; set; }
    public List<ErrorModel> ErrorList { get; set; }

    public List<ErrorModel> GetErrors()
    {
        string cs = "some path";

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
        {
            var listOfErrors = new List<ErrorModel>();
            string stm = "SELECT * FROM Error WHERE Checked == 'False'";
            con.Open();

            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        listOfErrors.Add(new ErrorModel
                        {
                            Id = rdr["ID"].ToString()
                        });
                    }

                    rdr.Close();
                    ErrorList = listOfErrors;
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        return ErrorList;
    }
}

public interface IErrorRepository
{
    List<ErrorModel> GetErrors();
}
```

My controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private IErrorRepository _errorRepository;

    public ErrorController(IErrorRepository errorRepository)
    {
        _errorRepository = errorRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Error(int? page)
    {
        var errors = _errorRepository.GetErrors();

        //// stuff for paging
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1); // if there is no page, return page 1

        return View(errors.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
}
```

But the thing is, the controller is never being called.

I've changed it from a previous version where the controller was responsible for everything. So all I've done is I have moved the data accessing out into a separate class. The Error view is the same as it was before. Have I missed some detail in my implementation?

UPDATE:

I've fiddled around with the constructor a little, and I have a few questions. How come the following code where I inject it in the constructor doesn't work:

```
    public ErrorController(IErrorRepository _errorRepository)
    {
        this._errorRepository = _errorRepository;
    }
```

But if I change it to this, the controller gets called and everything seems to work fine:

```
    public ErrorController()
    {
        _errorRepository = new ErrorRepository();
    }
```

But isn't the last example a bad way of doing it, since ErrorController is still tightly couple to ErrorRepository?

UPDATE 2:

I made this custom controller factory:

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerType");
            }
            if (!typeof (IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type requested is not a controller: {0}", controllerType.Name), "controllerType");
            }
            return MvcUnityContainer.Container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public static class MvcUnityContainer
{
    public static UnityContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

And this bootstrapper class to set all the dependencies:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IErrorRepository, ErrorRepository>();
        MvcUnityContainer.Container = container;

        return container;
    }
}
```

Which I then initialise in the Global.asax file:

```
        // Initialise IoC container
        Bootstrapper.Initialise();
        // Register custom controller factory
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(ControllerFactory));
```

Now I can use constructor injection and thus decouple my ErrorController from my ErrorRepository:

```
    public ErrorController(IErrorRepository errorRepository)
    {
        this.errorRepository = errorRepository;
    }
```

Comment: do you have some sort of IoC that injects the `IErrorController`?  It is most likely failing to hit the controller, because you dont have an empty constructor and probably don't have an DI setup.

Comment: do you use IoC to inject the `IErrorRepository`? How is it being created?

Comment: What do you mean by "the controller is never being called"? What request do you make and what response do you get?

Comment: @Johan No IoC. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: In response to your update, the 1st doesn't work because you haven't set up a DI container (Autofac, [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), Unity, etc) to actually inject an instance of `ErrorRepository` into your `ErrorController` to satisfy the dependency on `IErrorRepository`. With a DI container, you register which types should be used to satisfy the dependencies, and the container can then handle creating an instance of that type and provide it to the controller. And correct, the 2nd way is tightly coupled to `ErrorRepository` and should be avoided, because it's not possible to isolate.

Comment: Instead of declaring a class level property `ErrorList`, you'll probably just want to return the instance variable `listOfErrors` from your repository.

Comment: In an MVC application, where would it usually be fitting to declare and invoke the method registering the container?

Comment: @Khaine775 That just depends on your choice of DI container. I have used Ninject, and that has a special attribute that registers it to run at startup. With others, you may add something to global.asax. Just pick a well known DI container and examine their documentation for how to register it and set up the dependencies.

Comment: Now that you have mastered the Repository pattern, why not move on to the next step and implement the Service pattern where all the logic is taken out of the controller and performed in a service. This service separates the business logic from the UI logic and is injected in the same way you are injecting your repository. An example is the accepted answer in this thread: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/repository-service-design-pattern

Comment: I'll definitely look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to fix it by reading through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797132/Dependency-Injection-in-MVC-Using-Unity-IoC-Contai) excellent post on how to make a IoC with Unity. I've updated the OP with my final code.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Ninject is a nice IoC container. You can download and run my ASP.NET MVC project from [here](https://github.com/yeasin90/SQLite-MVC-application-with-Repository-Pattern/tree/master/CriminalSearch). I have used Dependency Injection from lower level to higher level. Hope this will give you an idea about the Ninject framework and why we maintain Dependency Inversion Principle

Comment: Do you mean Dependency Injection principle or Inversion of Control principle? lol

Comment: It's Dependency Inversion Principle. It's done by Inversion of Control. Dependency Injection is one way to Invert the Control, thus we maintain Dependency Inversion Principle. :)